# Shortcut for selector tool in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a shortcut for the selector tool in Photoshop (the very fist tool in the tool bar, the one selected when opening Photoshop) ?

Comment: That's the Move tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All tool shortcuts are listed if you choose <kbd>Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd> and choose **Tools** from the drop down.

The move tool's shortcut is <kbd>v</kbd>

[image: shortcuts]

For tools with sub-tools, you can right-click/control-click the tool for the pop out and the shortcut will be shown to the right of the tools.

[image: tools]

***Adding Brenden's comment to this answer so it's more complete:***

If you have Tool Tips active in the preferences, you can also simply hover your mouse over any of the tools and the shortcut will appear as a tool tip.

[image: tip]

Comment: Beat me by about a minute :P So I'll just comment on yours: You can also mouse over any of the toolbar items to see their shortcuts. Like so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5XFyD.png

Comment: @Brendan, yup I should have added that. I did due to your comment.

Comment: Thanks guys ! (sidenote: when I hover toolbar items I don't get any tool tip :/)

Comment: Tool Tips have to be checked in the preferences and sometimes it takes a few moment of no mouse movement for the tip to appear.